# How to declare module_name in groups Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

I used this code in a xml view in ideas_app module:

```
groups="group_vote_user"
```

but i got this error "External ID must be fully qualified"

Is it really need module name like `groups="ideas_app.group_vote_user"` even this view in same module with group_vote_user security (in module ideas_app)?

Is there any ways to not declare module name or change with `this.group_vote_user` like that?

Comment: Study basic things on the odoo documentation before working further@BazzB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to check sequence of files in manifest file. For example, *security.xml* should be come first and then others view files.

I am not sure if there is a way to change it. But as per standards, we need to follow standard way like *"module_name.xml_ID"*